# Why the size of uint8_t is 8 Byte after convert from 20Byte NSData in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, uint8t

I am developing in **ios objective-c BLE** , I receive the **BLE data** and print by `NSLog` like the following:

```
NSData *initialData = [characteristic value];
NSData *startOfFrameData = [initialData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];
NSLog(@"StartOfFrameData: %@", startOfFrameData);
```

The data in the log is like the following:

```
StartOfFrameData: <04621281 00931012 fed0d499 e92ceaac 3286513e>
```

But it only has 8 Byte after I convert it to the `uint8_t` via the following code:

```
uint8_t *tempData1=(uint8_t *)[startOfFrameData bytes];
NSLog(@"before tempData1:%lu", sizeof(tempData1));
for(int i = 0;i<sizeof(tempData1);i++){
   NSLog(@"tempData1[%d] = %x , %d",i,tempData1[i],tempData1[i]);
}
```

The log show like the following:

```
tempData1:8
tempData1[0] = f4 , 244
tempData1[1] = 9b , 155
tempData1[2] = b2 , 178
tempData1[3] = 81 , 129
tempData1[4] = 0 , 0
tempData1[5] = 6 , 6
tempData1[6] = 5 , 5
tempData1[7] = 71 , 113
```

Why it only has 8 Byte after covert to `uint_8` ?

Did I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop you are asking for the size of `tempData1`.  `tempData1` is of type `uint_8t *` which is a pointer. Pointers contain memory addresses and in this case the memory address is 8 bytes.

You should probably iterate up to `startOfFrameData.length`.

For example:

```
uint8_t *tempData1 = (uint8_t *)[startOfFrameData bytes];

for(int i = 0; i < startOfFrameData.length; i++){
   NSLog(@"tempData1[%d] = %x , %d",i,tempData1[i],tempData1[i]);
}
```